# ¿Cómo comprobar si existe una llave con un valor específico en un diccionario en Python? Diccionario con arreglos como valores

Tags: python-3.x, array, condiciones, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario `the_dictionary_list:`, inicializado como se muestra a continuación:

```
the_dictionary_list= {'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png',
'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'],
'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 'Ojos':
['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 'Pinzas':
['Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 'Puas':
['Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

Quería evaluar sí este diccionario tiene una combinación particular de llave y valor(dentro de su arreglo), entonces escribí el siguiente código:

```
if ('Color', 'None') in the_dictionary_list.items():
    print('Esto es verdad')
else:
    print('Esto es falso')
    
if ('Color', 'Amarillo.png') in the_dictionary_list.items():
    print('Esto es verdad')
else:
    print('Esto es falso')
```

La salida fue la siguiente:

> Esto es falso
>
> Esto es falso

La cual es 50% falsa, dado que la segunda condición debería imprimir `Esto es verdad`, traté de buscar respuestas en otros sitios, pero parece que los diccionarios con arreglos por dentro son muy poco comunes, pero aceptables al final, ¿de qué otra manera puedo evaluar si un par particular de clave-valor existe realmente en el diccionario anterior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes lograr con la siguiente función

```
def existe(llave, valor, dicc):
    return llave in dicc and valor in dicc[llave]
```

que recibe una llave, un valor y un diccionario. Primero revisa que la llave esté definida en el diccionario (`llave in dicc`) y luego que la lista `dicc[llave]` contenga el valor (`valor in dicc[llave]`).

#### Demo

```
the_dictionary_list= {
    'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'],
    'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'],
    'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'],
    'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'],
    'Pinzas': ['Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'],
    'Puas': ['Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}

def existe(llave, valor, dicc):
    return llave in dicc and valor in dicc[llave]

print(existe('Color', None, the_dictionary_list))
print(existe('Color', 'Amarillo.png', the_dictionary_list))
```

produce:

```
False
True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ¡Ay Caramba! Que bueno eres tío Moe